# how to get all modules and get all controllers in nestjs?

Tags: javascript

I hope to easily access all enabled modules and controllers in the main.ts file of NestJS. I need to read the paths of controllers in order to generate documentation that meets my requirements.

I couldn't find any documentation on how to use reflection to obtain modules or controllers on the NestJS official website.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.